# SharpDX Bitmaps

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, direct2d, sharpdx

I've been looking around the internet for a while, and I can't seem to find the answer I've been looking for. So what I intend to do with bitmaps is I want to draw them onto the window, and be able properly resize them whenever. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you considering SharpDX (Direct2D?)? WPF or Windows Phone/Windows App both have technologies for drawing arbitrary paths that will be a lot simpler to use especially as you change sizes.

Comment: Because i'm developing a game engine, not a regular desktop application, or app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who do not know, you can use matrices to translate, resize, and rotate. Here's how to do it. Also be sure to change the Matrix for the RenderTarget before you draw the actual object.

[Vector2](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-vector2--ctor-1)

[RenderTarget.Transform](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/p-sharpdx-direct2d1-rendertarget-transform)

[RenderTarget.DrawBitmap](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct2d1-rendertarget-drawbitmap)

[Matrix.Transformation2D](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-matrix-transformation2d-1)

```
Vector2 center = new Vector2(bitmap.Size.Width / 2, bitmap.Size.Height / 2);
renderTarget.Transform = Matrix.Transformation2D(center, 0f, new Vector2(width / bitmap.Size.Width, height / bitmap.Size.Height), center, MathHelper.ToRads(rotation), new Vector2(x - center.X, y - center.Y));
renderTarget.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 1f, BitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor);
renderTarget.Transform = Matrix.Transformation2D(Vector2.Zero, 0f, new Vector2(1f, 1f), Vector2.Zero, MathHelper.ToRads(0), Vector2.Zero);
```

Comment: Thanks for following up and answering the question with what you figured out.

Comment: No problem, i'd like for others to have an easier time than I did when finding the answer. I also updated the answer with how to change everything back afterwards.